# Dual wield 1H vs 1H + Quiver vs 2H + Quiver?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

As a demon hunter, you have three choices:

1. Dual Weld 1H crossbows
2. 1H crossbow + quiver
3. 2H crossbow/bow + quiver

Given equivalent level items of all of these types, in every single situation I have ALWAYS found the 2H crossbow/bow + quiver to be the highest dps of the three combos. Next highest is 1H crossbow + quiver and the lowest dps is dual weld 1H crossbows.

Is there ever a reason you would ever choose anything but a 2H crossbow/bow + quiver for end game dps? Are there other important factors to think about besides DPS (like attack speed)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In general, 1H + Quiver and Dual Wield setups are only worthwhile if the itemization available to you makes them worthwhile. That is to say, if you have access to much a better 1-hander than a 2-hander, than using it instead may make sense, even with a quiver. If you have *two of them*, dual wielding might even be an option, as there are some stat affixes that will not appear on a Quiver.

That said, thanks to the **Archery** passive, 2H weapons will generally pull ahead, since a Quiver offsets the normal loss of stats that occurs when using a 2H weapon, the only thing you really give up is the opportunity to equip a shield, and the defensive benefits thereof. But at the end of the day, with items as heavily random as they are, you'll always want to evaluate every weapon individually -  don't rule out a hand xbow just because it isn't a 2 hander. With the right stats, it can still be an upgrade.

Comment: Bravo! Well spoken good sir!

Answer (score 1):

The ideal 2x 1H would probably be 1000+ dps, 250+ dex, 11% att speed (ain't realy sure what the cap is), +crit dmg, socket.
Add the 15% att speed from dual-wield, and you could dish out some serious dps.
You would probably never see the big numbers you see with an 2H, but much quicker attack speed would cover for that.

2H+quiver for pure dps is the most economical choice, since you get good dps, for less money.

Answer (score 1):

I do fine using 2 1-handed crossbows, can clear anything on inferno. If you choose to dual wield make sure the DPS is close, or the same, as a single 2-handed weapon.

Answer (score 0):

dual wielding is actually viable if they both had sockets, and they both had increased crit dps. Archery passive gives 10% crit chance with 1h xbows, and if you put good emeralds in both the 1h.. thats a lot of bonus crit dmg. Now all you need is high base dps, and moar crit dmg/chance/aspd

Answer (score 0):

You failed to note a 4th option for Demon Hunters, 1H crossbow plus shield which can add substantial defence to your take 30% more damage than barbarian or monk build :)

If your build needs to add +resist all or needs it's block increased the stats on a shield usually play in that favour.